# Methods after has_one_attached don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage to store images but and doesn't work for a specific model, first an example with a working model:

```
class GalleryImage < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

In this case everything works well, here is the console output:

```
2.7.0 :006 > ::GalleryImage.new.image
 => #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x0000557a5b57b1f8 @name="image" ...>>
```

But, I have another model called `AppSetting` like this:

```
class AppSetting < ApplicationRecord
  def hola
    'hola'
  end

  has_one_attached :gimmick

  def adios
    'adios'
  end
end
```

And, when I try it in the rails console:

```
2.7.0 :006 > ::AppSetting.new.hola
 => "hola" 
2.7.0 :007 > ::AppSetting.new.gimmick
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):7
NoMethodError (undefined method `gimmick' for #<AppSetting:0x0000560cb955b470>)
2.7.0 :008 > ::AppSetting.new.adios
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):7
        1: from (irb):8:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `adios' for #<AppSetting:0x0000560cb94241d8>)
```

As you can see, the first method (`hola`) works well, but I'm getting `NoMethodError (undefined method...` error message for the next methods.

any help? please.

Comment: Very strange. I made the same model with the same methods and everything works. Have you tried to use these methods not in `rails c` but in some controller? Maybe the console is broken. My version of ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.2. You can also try to move `has_one_attached: gimmick` over the` def hola` method

Comment: Thanks for your time! Yes, I tried on controllers and I get the same (NoMethodError) error, and any method above has_one_attached works well, but any method below has_one_attached doesn't work.